# How to loop inside array and assign to a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, function

In my angular2 application which contains checkboxes; the checkbox keys are stored in an array named "ticketselected" and the selected check boxes keys are stored in "selectedArray". I want to assign these keys one by one to a variable and use that variable. I need to splice an array. How can I implement this?

what I have done is:

component.ts

```
this.ticketSelected
    .map((entry, key) => {
         if (entry == true) {
             selectedArray.push(key);
            }
     })

 var index =   // This should be key
 allTickets.splice(index, 1);
```

'**selectedArray**' contains all selected keys.

How should I implement this?

EDIT

```
 deleteRequest
      .subscribe((data: any) => { // this data contain deleted data ie like {count:1}
                this.ticketSelected
                     .map((entry, key) => {
                      if (entry === true) {
                                selectedArray.push(key);
                       }
                 })

                 selectedArray.forEach((item) => {
                        var index = allTickets.indexOf(item);
                        console.log("index", index);
                        if (index != -1){
                            allTickets.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                    });
                })
```

Comment: First of all, replace `entry == true` with `entry === true` if you want to check the ___value___ of `entry`. Otherwise, that condition is going to be `true` for [any truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Answer (score 3):

You should use `indexOf` method.

```
allTickets=allTickets.filter(function(item){
     return selectedArray.indexOf(item.id)==-1;
});
```

Atnoher solution is to use `filter` method which accepts a `callback` function, applied to every item in the `array`.

Read more [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. i use this indexOf method. but it always return -1 . am adding my edited code.

Comment: @NidhiMalhotra, you have syntax error in your edit. Maybe it is a mistake.

Comment: This line :`if (index != -1){allTickets);` must be `if (index != -1){`

Comment: Please tell me you is the structure of `allTickets`

Comment: all tickets is array of objects like :[object, object, object]

Comment: What fields contains ? For instance: id, name, etc

Comment: you want to delete from allTickets where clientId is in selectedArray ?

Comment: no i want to delete data based on id. actually delete operation done sucessfully and i got the response {count: 1}(in delete request.subscribe). and i nee to splice the deleted data from the allTicketArray. am including my all delete code.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: is this instead of previous selectedArray.forEach right?

Comment: @NidhiMalhotra,yes

Comment: i gave it exactly as you said. then how can i splice the array(allTickets)

Comment: I don't use splice method, i used filter method.